# How to remove entire string that match specific pattern in unix txt file with a single command line

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, tcl

I would like to remove all the strings that contain "vcc".

Example:

```
    s_regscan_ctrl_lab_2_regscan_ce[0] s_regscan_data_l_regscan s_t_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan vcc_cram_viort1_6_t 
 vcc_cram_viort1_7_t vcc_cram_viort1_8_t vcc_cram_viort1_9_t vcc_cram_vioxio1_0_t 
 vcc_cram_vioxio1_1_t vcc_cram_vioxio1_2_t vcc_cram_vioxio2_0_t vcc_cram_vioxio2_1_t 
 vcc_cram_vioxio2_2_t vcchg vccl vssgnd m_b_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan
```

Expected output:

```
    s_regscan_ctrl_lab_2_regscan_ce[0] s_regscan_data_l_regscan s_t_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan vssgnd m_b_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan
```

I have tried with:

```bash
cat abc.txt | sed 's/\svcc.*\s//g'"
```

But it removed everything after vcc* and returned:

```
s_regscan_ctrl_lab_2_regscan_ce[0] s_regscan_data_l_regscan s_t_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome, when you say *"contain"* do you mean words that *start* with `vcc`? Probably your text doesn't have words like `foo_vcc`, but if there were, should those words be removed too?

Comment: Yes, i would like to remove words like ```foo_vcc``` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to proceed, but I'll try my best.

If you want to remove every occurrence of the string `vcc` in a text file (note you don't need to use `cat`:

```bash
sed 's/vcc//g' abc.txt
```

Use the `-i` switch on the `sed` command to write modifications in the file.

If you want to remove all lines containing `vcc`:

```bash
grep -v "vcc" abc.txt
```

If you want to remove every word (I mean here strings separated by spaces):

```bash
sed 's/\b\w*vcc\w*\b//g' abc.txt
```

Comment: HI, I do not want to remove the entire line, only the words that contain "vcc".
For example, i would like to remove the string such as "vccaab", "vcc123s", etc... in a text file

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I edited my answer, I hope it better fits to your needs

Comment: I modified once again, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535687/19977125). The new one I use now matches the word even if the `vcc` string isn't at the beginning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl)

```bash
$ cat abc.txt
    s_regscan_ctrl_lab_2_regscan_ce[0] s_regscan_data_l_regscan s_t_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan vcc_cram_viort1_6_t
 vcc_cram_viort1_7_t vcc_cram_viort1_8_t vcc_cram_viort1_9_t vcc_cram_vioxio1_0_t
 vcc_cram_vioxio1_1_t vcc_cram_vioxio1_2_t vcc_cram_vioxio2_0_t vcc_cram_vioxio2_1_t
 vcc_cram_vioxio2_2_t vcchg vccl vssgnd m_b_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan
```

if we have `remove_vcc.tcl` as

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
set fid [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
  set words [split $line]
  set filtered [lmap word $words {
    if {[string match {*vcc*} $word]} then continue else {string cat $word}
  }]
  set newline [join $filtered]
  if {[string trim $newline] ne ""} {
    puts $newline
  }
}
close $fid
```

then

```bash
$ tclsh remove_vcc.tcl abc.txt
    s_regscan_ctrl_lab_2_regscan_ce[0] s_regscan_data_l_regscan s_t_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan
 vssgnd m_b_regscan_data_tieoff_regscan
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  printf "%s", ($i ~ /vcc/) ? "" :  $i OFS}END{print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this simple `awk` one-liner:

```bash
cat abc.txt | awk -v RS=" " '!/vcc/ {print $0}'
```

or from your example my guess is you want to remove `vcc` if it is in the beginning instead just containing it somewhere, so I would rather use this:

```bash
cat abc.txt | awk -v RS=" " '!/^vcc/ {print $0}'
```

Comment: Hi, i have tested above but bumped into error:
> cat abc.txt | awk -v RS=" " '!/^vcc/ {print $0}'
```/: Event not found.```

Comment: Oh interesting. This error usually occurs when it tries to look up the shells history. Which shell are you using? And are you using ssh by any chance?^^